# How to define the type of a field in the field calculator so that the rasterize (vector to raster) tool recognize it?

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile (polygon) that I want to rasterize by an attribute but the rasterize tool does not recognize the right field. When I create a new field using the field calculator it does not matter what type I choose (integer, real, ...) the result is qlonglong (integer64), a type that the rasterize tool apparently does not recognize.

Comment: Which QGIS version do you use? Sounds like a bug report

Comment: I am running Qgis 2.18.7. I solved the problem using the rasterize tool from the processing toolbox. However the fact that the filed calculator seems to ignore the "type" you choose when creating a new field seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a list of fields that contains different type of fields: `integer`, `String`, and `qlonglong (integer64)`.

[image]

If you access the Rasterize tool from `Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to raster)` you will see only the fields that are `integer` type.

[image]

To get `integer` type not `qlonglong (integer64)`, the length should be from `1 to 9` when you define a new field, as you can see below:

[image]

However, if you accessed the Rasterize (Vector to raster) tool from `Processing toolbox -> GDAL/OGR -> [GDAL] Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to raster)`, you will get every type in the attribute table even the string type, as you can see below:

[image]

My recommendation is to use the rasterize tool from Processing toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The Rasterize (Vector to raster) tool from Processing toolbox reads other types than "int".