# Datatype changed to qlonglong from integer when export to shp and SQL

Tags: sql, shp2pgsql

I have a view that basis on the table 'mytable' with these columns:

[image]

The view created as

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW viewbox.myview AS
SELECT mytable.h AS height,
mytable.geom
FROM mytable;
```

with columns

[image]

When trying to export to shp -> sql

```
shp2pgsql -s 3857 -I -g geometry /data/relief_poly.shp relief_poly > /data/relief_poly.sql
```

I get

[image]

and in SQL column "height" is float8!

I am not really plugged in to the case why my column datatype changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/240350/90384), qlonglong is integer64 in QGIS, because length is more than 9. So, to get integer type not qlonglong (integer64), the length should be from 1 to 9. I recreated table column with SMALLINT type and rewrote my view -> in SQL column height is integer!